# Angular 2 with router 3.0.0-beta.2 : is it possible to have wildcard beside children?

Tags: angular, angular2-router3

I would like to have a dynamic route like /parent/:id beside other /parent/child.

I tried something like this with no success:

`export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'parent', component: ParentComponent,canActivate: [ WebpackAsyncRoute ], 
    children: [
        { path: ':id', component: 'ParamComponent' },
        { path: 'child', component: 'ChildComponent' },
        { path: 'anotherchild', component: 'AnotherChildComponent' }
    ]
  }
];`

Comment: Have you tried? What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is Yes. The problem was I didn't add the :id path on the route config defined on the component (as I'm using WebpackAsyncRoute). so nothing related to the wildcard path